# Is there a way to create a vector field from a list of vectors in numpy?

Tags: python, vector, calculus

I have some code where I record a list of vectors over a trajectory. For each of these I have the N dimensional point from which it originates, and the vector from that point.

I have all of these ordered in an array from start to finish, and I would like to have these N dimensional vectors placed at points in the space relating to their origin so that I can calculate the divergence.

Example origin points:

```
[[-0.03194652 -0.02481244  0.02337171 -0.04088087]
 [-0.03244277  0.16996671  0.02255409 -0.32609914]
 [-0.02904343  0.3647604   0.01603211 -0.61158502]
 [-0.02174823  0.16941809  0.00380041 -0.31389597]
 [-0.01835986 -0.02575779 -0.00247751 -0.02001695]
 [-0.01887502  0.1693996  -0.00287785 -0.31348053]
 [-0.01548703 -0.02568124 -0.00914746 -0.02170657]
 [-0.01600065 -0.22067082 -0.00958159  0.26807625]
 [-0.02041407 -0.02541345 -0.00422007 -0.02761331]
 [-0.02092234  0.16976877 -0.00477233 -0.32162472]]
```

Example vectors at each point

```
[[-0.00049625  0.19477914 -0.00081762 -0.28521826]
 [ 0.00339933  0.19479369 -0.00652198 -0.28548588]
 [ 0.00729521 -0.19534231 -0.0122317   0.29768905]
 [ 0.00338836 -0.19517588 -0.00627792  0.29387903]
 [-0.00051516  0.19515739 -0.00040034 -0.29346358]
 [ 0.00338799 -0.19508084 -0.00626961  0.29177396]
 [-0.00051362 -0.19498958 -0.00043413  0.28978282]
 [-0.00441342  0.19525737  0.00536152 -0.29568956]
 [-0.00050827  0.19518221 -0.00055227 -0.29401141]
 [ 0.00339538 -0.19505367 -0.00643249  0.29117411]]
```

I attempted to use np.meshgrid over the initial points for each dimension, but I had to use sparse=True to save memory.

I am a bit stuck here, can anyone help?

Edit:

For my specific example I have a particle x in 4 dimensional space.
I have a collection of trajectories in a list for it moving through this N dimensional space of a set length of 10 time steps. Each entry in the trajectory is an entry [(t_start, t_end)]

```
initial_array = []
vector_array = []
for trajectory in range(trajectories):
    for t in range(timesteps):
        initial_state = trajectory[t][0]
        vector_at_state = trajectory[t][0] - initial_state
        initial_array.append(initial_state)
        vector_array.append(vector_at_state)
 return np.array(initial_array), np.array(vector_array)
```

I then want to plot these vectors at the points they began from to generate a "sample" vector field from what I can observe, and then use this function:

```
def divergence(f, h):
    num_dims = len(f)
    return np.ufunc.reduce(np.add, [np.gradient(f[i], h[i],axis=i) for i in range(num_dims)])
```

To calculate the divergence over the sampled trajectories.

Comment: it sounds intersting but - sorry - it's not very clear what you really are seeking for. Usually a trajectory is a journey from one point to the next. And it might be,  that you have at each point an additional vector that indicates some direction or gradient.  Can you try to express your question by some vector equations ?

Comment: @pyano I have added some additional information, hopefully this provides clarity?

Comment: without a complete and running example it is difficult to help. I would have to setup a complete test environment myself....